# elasticsearch search request size limit error

Tags: elasticsearch

me elasticsearch version 7.9.3 (running on ubuntu) holds an index of each day (logs)
so when a query needs to include for example data from 2020-01-01 until 2020-11-20

Search query will look like this: (which returns error 400)

```
http://localhost:9200/log_2020-02-14,log_2020-02-26,log_2020-02-27,log_2020-04-24,log_2020-04-25,log_2020-07-17,log_2020-08-01,log_2020-09-09,log_2020-09-21,log_2020-10-06,log_2020-10-07,log_2020-10-08,log_2020-10-16,log_2020-10-17,log_2020-10-18,log_2020-10-21,log_2020-10-22,log_2020-11-12/_search?pretty
```

I know I can split the request into two but I don't see why (4096 bytes over HTTP it's not so big)

any chance to config this issue ?

response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "too_long_frame_exception",
                "reason": "An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes."
            }
        ],
        "type": "too_long_frame_exception",
        "reason": "An HTTP line is larger than 4096 bytes."
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

URLs cannot exceed a [certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/4604579) depending on the medium. Elasticsearch limits that length to 4096 bytes.

Since you seem to be willing to query all indexes of 2020 since January 1st until today (Nov 20), you can use a wildcard like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/log_2020*/_search?pretty
```

Another way is by leveraging aliases and put all your 2020 indexes behind the `log_2020` alias:

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions" : [
    { "add" : { "index" : "log_2020*", "alias" : "log_2020" } }
  ]
}
```

After running that you can query the alias directly

```
http://localhost:9200/log_2020/_search?pretty
```

If you want to make sure that all your daily indexes get the alias upon creation you can add an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html#_index_template_with_index_aliases)

```
PUT _index_template/my-logs
{
  "index_patterns" : ["log_2020*"],
  "template": {
    "aliases" : {
        "log_2020" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to query between 2020-03-04 and 2020-09-21, you can query the `log_2020` alias with a `range` query on your date field

```
POST log_2020/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2020-03-04",
        "lt": "2020-09-22"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks that help

but let's say i want all the days between 2020-03-04 and 2020-09-21

how do I alias this ?

Comment: I guess your indexes also have a date field in it, right? if that's the case you can query the whole alias but add a `range` query on that date field with the desired min/max dates

Comment: It wont affect profrmanc?, Its not much faster to query only the index u actually need?

Comment: That's the whole point of running queries over aliases. ES is smart is enough to figure out which indexes to search. Try it out and you'll see